# How to teleport back to my freighter?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Since the newest [Desolation Update](https://www.nomanssky.com/desolation-update/) (v2.60) [Teleporters](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Base_Teleport_Module) can now be built aboard Freighter Bases. The changelog says "These variants do not require power. They can be used to teleport to other teleporters, or to the Space Station."

I have successfully built such a Teleporter on my freighter without any further requirements like a [Base Computer](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Base_Computer). My first teleportation worked as expected.

But how can I return?

Does the changelog entry means that we can teleport FROM the freighter to any other known teleporter, but NOT BACK to the freighter?

Or do you know how to choose the freighters teleporter as destination address?

Comment: I guess you can't. Why? Because freighter can be anywhere and it's not static coordinates in the list. It's already a huge QoL improvement to get back into action fast. But to get onto one you still have to summon it and just fly there and land. The restriction is probably to prevent abuses, balance other forms of travel and avoid uncertainties (technical problems), since you can summon freighter: in stationless systems, inside missions (correct?), space events (right?), etc.

Comment: ^ They've definitely mentioned before that it's really hard to allow you to teleport into Freighters because of how they exist in a nonstatic spot in the middle of space. Agreed it would be nice, but I think it's a big technical block

Comment: I don't see the difference between a Teleporter on a freighter in space and a Teleporter in a Space Station in space. They could just use the name of my freighter as Teleporter-"Address", not? It is also known where my freighter actually is located (as seen on the galactic map).

Comment: @n_plum, reference to such information should be good to post an answer. Would be useful for OP, me and all future readers.

Comment: It's been a while since I read that, and unfortunately searching for where hello games had talked about it isn't coming up because of the new desolation update stuff :/

Answer (score 2):

For sake of clarity and visibility, I am adding this reply.

Freighter teleporters are ***one-way***, like the one in the Anomaly. You can teleport ***from*** the freighter to another location but not from another location to the freighter. It is also worth noticing that while teleporting from the Anomaly to another locations gives the option to return to the Anomaly by using a specific command in the menu (that disappears as soon as another teleport is used), the freighter **does not provide that option**.

As for the why... it is a tad unclear. Some theorized that a freighter can be moved so technically the space it was when you left could be occupied by something else now ***especially in multyplayer***, but that does not explain why the Anomaly (that can also be moved) has a different behavior implemented.

The most probable reason for this limit is that having the ability to teleport back to the freighter could potentially be abused in multiplayer to bypass the "one freighter per system" limit that probably exist due to some technical limitations in how the freighter base are implemented. Note that this is just a theory, but I know that a famous mod that tried to bypass the 1 freighter in a system limit caused a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[image]In creative mode, I've build cubic rooms and corridors on freighter (only works from 2nd floor up) and placed exterior doors. This allowed me to exit on freighter and placed a base computer (among other stuff like a landing pad).
Teleporting to this base puts me in empty space with the current ship next to me "landed".
It appears to be a confusion regarding coordinates.
In normal mode, the base computer can be placed but does not appear.

While taking this picture, I realized the base computer is gone. The base name is still on. I also did not move the freighter yet.